# Azure databricks shortcut to show the line alignment

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-databricks

what's the shortcut to turn on/off the indentation alignment lines? as shown in the image? Thanks

[image: click here for image]

get shortcut on using Azure databricks notebooks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

> You can change the indentation of multiple lines by highlighting the lines and using the `Tab` key. You can un-indent using `Shift + Tab`.

If you want to turn on/off the indentation alignment lines for the complete code, just select the complete code and use indent selection to turn on and unindent selection to turn off.

OR

After select multiple line, Indent: `Ctrl+]` Unindent: `Ctrl+[`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help,CHEEKATLAPRADEEP. I tried the shortcuts you recommended, it  changed the indentation but the vertical alignment lines are still there. Is there shortcut to turn on/off the vertical lines?